# Using parse with Angular.js and not Backbone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, parse-platform

Parse.com natively supports Backbone.js. I have used Angular.js previously and would want to further my knowledge in it, though in Backbone I'm still uninitiated. Has any of you implemented Parse with Angular and also is it worth the extra effort to learn Backbone for easy implementation with Parse?

PS: Links to any parse angular projects you are aware of would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually only **[Parse JS SDK](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide)** that is similar to Backbone.js, not Parse itself. You can use Angular.js perfectly fine by having its `$http` service talking directly to **[Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide)**.

You can still want to use Parse JS SDK (I wouldn't call it "natively supports", it just using similar API), it is also not a big deal. You just need to convert your plain objects into Parse objects when saving, and whenever result objects arrive from Parse, you convert them into plain objects via `.toJSON()` method.

The downside of the SDK (with or without Angular) is the overhead of loading another massive JS script, which can potentially slow down your app.